# How to put divider line between TextView lines

Tags: android, textview

i have long text and want to put divider between text view lines. something like image below.

do you have any offer?

update: all the things is clear!!! i want to separate text lines with divider or simple line. i could not find any thing in web, so decide to ask you guys. thanks ;)

[image: example]

Comment: "underline text" did you mean it  ?

Comment: not exactly. just like the photo. the line should fill textView and also textview contain a line on top.